# Maven fails on compile java project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, log4j2

From eclipse I am trying to perform a maven install but I gets some errors:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building analyzer 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ distributed.analyzer ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 9 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ distributed.analyzer ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 14 source files to D:\eclipse-workspace\DistributedAnalyzer\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Analizador.java:[8,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Analizador.java:[9,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Analizador.java:[22,30] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Logger
  location: class com.distributed.analyzer.Analizador
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Ordenante.java:[7,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Ordenante.java:[8,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Ordenante.java:[31,30] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Logger
  location: class com.distributed.analyzer.Ordenante
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Manager.java:[8,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Manager.java:[9,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Manager.java:[22,30] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Logger
  location: class com.distributed.analyzer.Manager
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Main.java:[6,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Main.java:[7,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Main.java:[22,30] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Logger
  location: class com.distributed.analyzer.Main
[INFO] 12 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 19.481 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-02-12T20:04:47+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/184M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project distributed.analyzer: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Analizador.java:[8,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Analizador.java:[9,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Analizador.java:[22,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Logger
[ERROR] location: class com.distributed.analyzer.Analizador
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Ordenante.java:[7,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Ordenante.java:[8,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Ordenante.java:[31,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Logger
[ERROR] location: class com.distributed.analyzer.Ordenante
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Manager.java:[8,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Manager.java:[9,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Manager.java:[22,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Logger
[ERROR] location: class com.distributed.analyzer.Manager
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Main.java:[6,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Main.java:[7,32] package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/DistributedAnalyzer/src/main/java/com/distributed/analyzer/Main.java:[22,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Logger
[ERROR] location: class com.distributed.analyzer.Main
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

log4j2 jars are added as maven dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
  </dependency>
```

Also they are present in java build path in eclipse in the libraries tab.

I have added these two libraries in run/debug setting in eclipse, in the classpath tab.

Maven dependency tree:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-integration-jms</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
  </dependency> 
  </dependencies>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the output of mvn dependency:tree

Comment: are you sure you added them as build dependencies and not in dependencyManagement as people often do? Also as error suggests running with -X may help.

Comment: Did you update the maven project before doing the build. in Eclipse if can be done by going to Project > Right click > Maven > Update Project.

Comment: @user3509208 Yes I did, and also I force to update snapshots and releases.

Comment: @user3509208 ok, after update the maven project and force update snapshots and releases, maven install seems to work correctly. Many thx.

Comment: @KirilS. Yes, if I edit pom.xml file, I can see they are added as build dependencies and not in dependencyManagement.